# Why are routers so unsafe?

Tags: security, router

For a while I have enjoyed poking around all devices I can reach, and routers are no exception. By now, I have analysed 4 routers supplied by my ISP, and all of them have posed serious security flaws, aside of the poor default user/password scheme that most vendors seem to follow.

I find some of them particularly worrying, for example:

- Some Comtrend routers allow configuration via telnet. Most of the commands are read and run by an interpreter, but others are dispatched to sh, using 'sh -c COMMAND'. So if anyone types 'sysinfo && ls /', will see the root folder listed just after sysinfo's output. Someone "attempted" to patch that, in my current device if I type "&" in a command, it is invalidated. But I still can type 'ping || ls /', which should be a very ovious flaw, once they noticed and patched the first one. Why would anyone use 'sh -c' instead of fork/exec? (given that the telnet daemon is a binary, likely written in C)
- Comtrend Router CT-5624, an unauthorised user can access /password.cgi, which is the password change form, and that contains in a plain html comment the current password for each user. (Cannot find a CVE number, so refer to https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/18101/)
- Once an admin has logged in a ZyXEL Router P-660HN, anyone is allowed to enter the administration panel. Again no CVE: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/32204/
- CVE2012-2765 Affects a number of belkin devices that directly give away the MD5 hash of the admin password in the main admin page, the hash is directly used for logging in.

A quick search will reveal lots of security issues like these ones. 
I am far from being a security expert (I haven't even completed my bachelor) but even I can , which leads me to think that people who wrote this firmware don't really care about security at all, or actually care of doing things glitchy.

Is there any good explaination for these devices to be so unsafe?

Comment: There's a http://security.stackexchange.com/ where this would be on-topic.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I will consider it next time.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main answer is that horribly-insecure firmware doesn't hurt sales, because the general public doesn't know, and doesn't have the background to understand the problems.  So there's little profit in paying your engineers to do anything but the most straightforward "get it to work" implementation.